# Youtube flash player getDuration not accurate

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

For this video:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Hn3ISdjdK0
```

Youtube displays that the duration is 14 seconds and also a call to [GData API](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=3Hn3ISdjdK0) gives 14 seconds duration.

However using the [Youtube API getDuration()](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#getDuration) , I sometimes get 13.28 seconds

```
var videoDuration = flashPlayer.getDuration();
```

**Why the discrepancy ?**

This is how I construct the flashPlayer:

```
elements.container.flash({
        swf         : 'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3&start=' + settings.start , 
        id          : 'video_'+settings.safeID,
        height      : settings.height,
        width       : settings.width,
        allowScriptAccess:'always',
        wmode       : 'transparent',
        flashvars   : {
            "video_id"      : settings.videoID,
            "playerapiid"   : settings.safeID
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that YouTube simply rounds it upwards, as it's more correct to say that a 13.28s video is 14 seconds long instead of 13, as it's in fact longer than 13 seconds.

Comment: well the problem is the discrepancy between the two durations. if both returns the same duration, it will be all good

Comment: Test this on more videos and see if it's consistent that they get rounded upwards. Then it'll be safe to always round it.

Comment: i couldnt figure out why youtube is doing this, so i work around it.